# Mapping to similar times in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes like the following:

```
date/time
0  2/1/2016 10:32
1  2/1/2016 06:58
2  2/1/2016 01:47

 date/time  Quantity
0  2/1/2016 01:30        4
1  2/1/2016 10:45        6
2  2/1/2016 06:50        3
```

I am trying to map the "Quantity" column from the 2nd dataframe over to the first dataframe based on the datetime plus or minus 30 minutes.  So my final dataframe would like this:

```
        date/time  Quantity
0  2/1/2016 10:32     6
1  2/1/2016 06:58     3
2  2/1/2016 01:47     4
```

I tried adding additional columns for the different scenarios, mapping each additional column and then deleting all of my missing rows - I was wondering if there was a better way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

- `set_index`
- `sort_index`
- `reindex` with `method='nearest'` and `tolerance=pd.offsets.Minute(30)`

---

```
df2.set_index(
    'date/time'
).sort_index().reindex(
    df1['date/time'],
    method='nearest',
   tolerance=pd.offsets.Minute(30)
).reset_index()

            date/time  Quantity
0 2016-02-01 10:32:00         6
1 2016-02-01 06:58:00         3
2 2016-02-01 01:47:00         4
```